# WooCommerce: Get Product Variation ID from Matching Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

How I get product variation id from custom product loop.
I have variation attribute like,

```
{ 'pa_color'=>'red','pa_size'=>'large'}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set of attributes to match are

```
[
    'attribute_pa_color' => 'blue',
    'attribute_pa_size' => 'small',
];
```

Below is the function I ended up creating to achieve this:

```
/**
 * Find matching product variation
 *
 * @param $product_id
 * @param $attributes
 * @return int
 */
function find_matching_product_variation_id($product_id, $attributes)
{
    return (new \WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT())->find_matching_product_variation(
        new \WC_Product($product_id),
        $attributes
    );
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add a noteworthy comment about this answer. If you have a dynamic variation with multiple attributes, and one or multiple can contain the value of "any", then you must pass in a blank attribute as part of your array of attributes.

**Example:**

`
( new \WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT() )->find_matching_product_variation(
 $product,
 array(
  'attribute_pa_style' => '',
  'attribute_pa_color' => '',
  'attribute_pa_logo'  => '',
  'attribute_pa_size'  => 'small',
 )
);
`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get details on a particular product or loop, you can use this

Here is the full example code of find_matching_product_variation !

```
$product_id = 1;       //Added Specific Product id

$match_attributes =  array(
    "attribute_pa_color" => 'blue',
    "attribute_pa_size" => 'Large'
);

$data_store   = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
$variation_id = $data_store->find_matching_product_variation(
  new \WC_Product( $product_id),$match_attributes
);
```